# 'Kubectl' throws error 'failed to negotiate an api version' while installing using docker

Tags: linux, api, docker, kubernetes

I installed docker in machine using the guide in https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/ and I also installed Kubernetes in my local machine by using http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker/.

But once I run "kubectl get nodes" I get the error **error: failed to negotiate an api version; server supports: map[], client supports: map[v1:{} metrics/v1alpha1:{} extensions/v1beta1:{} componentconfig/v1alpha1:{} batch/v1:{} autoscaling/v1:{} authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1:{}]**.

The docker version on my machine is as follows.

- Client:

  - Version:      1.11.1
  - API version:  1.23
  - Go version:   go1.5.4
  - Git commit:   5604cbe
  - Built:        Tue Apr 26 23:30:23 2016
  - OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
- Server:

  - Version:      1.11.1
  - API version:  1.23
  - Go version: go1.5.4
  - Git commit:   5604cbe
  - Built:        Tue Apr 26 23:30:23 2016
  - OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Comment: As Nikhil mentioned, that error might not be related to the docker version. However, a lot of Kubernetes functionality *will* be broken on Kubernetes 1.2 with docker v1.11 (which was released after Kubernetes v1.2). We're working on docker v1.11 support for Kubernetes 1.3, and a lot of the problems should already be fixed at HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the server responded with an empty list of api versions that it supports.

Can you post the output of `kubectl version`?

That will print the git versions of kubectl and api server and will help us find if there is any incompatibility between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Ive tried using v1.3.0-alpha.3 of kubernetes with the same version of docker as the OP. I`m still having the same issue though. Should this be fixed in alpha.3 or do I need to wait for a new version ?